# Почему отстает state? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Почему при нажатии на `div` в консоле показывается старый `state`, хотя должен быть новый?

А при следующем нажатии показывается тот `state`, который должен был быть на первом нажатии:

```
<div key={index} 
     onClick={(e)=> {
       this.setState({currentTimeFilter: e.target.innerHTML})
       this._changeCurrent(e)}
     } 
     className="PlaylistSelect__item"
> 
  {option}
</div>

_changeCurrent(e){
  console.log('current', this.state.currentTimeFilter)
  e.target.closest('.PlaylistSelect').classList.remove('PlaylistSelect--active')
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Поскольку `setState` работает асинхронно, то для того что бы получить актуальное состояние стейта можно:

```
<div key={index} onClick={handleClick}> 
  {option} 
</div>
```

1. Использовать `prevState` *(назвать можно как угодно)*:

   ```
   handleClick (event) {
     this.setState(prevState => {
       console.log(prevSate)
       return {currentTimeFilter: event.target.innerHTML}
     )
   })
   ```
2. Добавить `callback` вторым параметром в `setSate`:

   ```
   handleClick (event) {
     this.setState({currentTimeFilter: event.target.innerHTML}, _changeCurrent)
   }

   _changeCurrent () {
     console.log("current", this.state.currentTimeFilter)
   }
   ```

*Отдельно стоит отметить что изменение имен классов **напрямую** не является рекомендованным способом взаимодействия с ними, что бы Ваше приложение работало оптимально лучше придерживаться именно [react-way'a](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html).*

Answer (score 8):

`setState` работает асинхронно. У вас сначала выполняется весь `onClick`, а потом уже `setState`

[документация](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html)

> В настоящее время setState работает асинхронно внутри обработчиков
> событий.
>
> Это даёт гарантию, например, когда Родитель и Ребёнок вызывают
> setState во время клика, Ребёнок не будет рендериться дважды. Вместо
> этого React «откладывает» обновление состояния в самый конец событий в
> браузере. Это помогает сильно повысить производительность больших
> приложений.

Кроме этого, ваш подход неправильный, т.к. вы изменяете DOM элемент в обход React и, если React'у потребуется перерисовать измененный элемент `.PlaylistSelect`, то он его перерисует без учета изменений, и он вновь будет иметь класс `PlaylistSelect--active`